# Why does my setState method not rebuild the UI of my Chat dialog (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I have a dialog Widget that renders a ChatUI which takes a List as an argument for the messages to display. Whenever I call the onSendPressed function of the Chat Widget, I want to send the message the user wrote, add this message to my _messages list, update the Chat Widget AND THEN based on what the user wrote calculate a response message, add that to the _messages list and update the Chat Widget again (so that the UI updates two times in total).

For some reason I haven't figured out yet my implementation does not work as intended, maybe one of you guys knows why? This is my code below:

```
String randomString() {
  final random = Random.secure();
  final values = List<int>.generate(16, (i) => random.nextInt(255));
  return base64UrlEncode(values);
}

class ChatDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatDialog({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChatDialogState createState() => _ChatDialogState();
}

class _ChatDialogState extends State<ChatDialog> {
  late DialogflowApi _dialog;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future _detectIntent(String text) async {
    // calculates the respective answer...

    return answer;
  }

  final List<types.Message> _messages = [];
  final _user = const types.User(id: '06c33e8b-e835-4736-80f4-63f44b66666c');
  final _user2 = const types.User(id: '03c33e8b-e835-4736-80f4-63f44b66666c');

  void _addMessage(types.Message message) {
    setState(() {
      _messages.insert(0, message);
    });
  }

  void _handleSendPressed(types.PartialText message) async {
    final textMessage = types.TextMessage(
      author: _user,
      createdAt: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      id: randomString(),
      text: message.text,
    );

    _addMessage(textMessage);

    print('added first message');

    final String answer = await _detectIntent(message.text) as String;

    final textMessage2 = types.TextMessage(
      author: _user2,
      createdAt: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      id: randomString(),
      text: answer,
    );

    _addMessage(textMessage2);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Dialog(
          backgroundColor: backgroundLight,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
          ),
          insetPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 500,
            left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65,
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 400,
              width: 200,
              child: Chat(
                theme: DefaultChatTheme(
                  inputBorderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(25.0),
                  ),
                  primaryColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                ),
                sendButtonVisibilityMode: SendButtonVisibilityMode.always,
                emptyState: const Center(
                  child: PTText(text: 'How can I help you'),
                ),
                messages: _messages,
                onSendPressed: _handleSendPressed,
                user: _user,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

You can ignore the print statements and the static ID's etc, just makes it easier for the moment to test things until they work.

What I want to happen is that after every of the two _addMessage calls, the UI is rebuild, what happens currently is that the UI os only rebuild once at the end of _handleSendPressed after calling _detectIntent

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a separate widget for the information that you are showing in the Dialog box.

Do let me know if it works.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Dialog(
          backgroundColor: backgroundLight,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
          ),
          insetPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 500,
            left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65,
          ),
          child: const DialogData(),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class DialogData extends StatelessWidget {
  const DialogData({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 400,
        width: 200,
        child: Chat(
          theme: DefaultChatTheme(
            inputBorderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(25.0),
            ),
            primaryColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          ),
          sendButtonVisibilityMode: SendButtonVisibilityMode.always,
          emptyState: const Center(
            child: PTText(text: 'How can I help you'),
          ),
          messages: _messages,
          onSendPressed: _handleSendPressed,
          user: _user,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, it is still updating only once at then end of _handleSendPressed